# Closed form solution of a sum in a sum

Tags: summation, closed-form

I am attempting to put:

$$a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n} [{n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k} (2+5k+3(n-k))]$$

where a=1/6, b=1/3, and c=1/2 into a closed form, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it. Is it possible to be done, and if so, how do I go about doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: You will be able to evaluate the inner sum as long as you can evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk b^k c^{n-k}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom nk b^k c^{n-k}$. Do you know the closed form for the first sum? In the second sum, what happens if you take the derivative of $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^k c^{n-k}$ with respect to $x$ and then multiply by $x$?

Comment: Yes, the closed form of the first sum is $(b+c)^{n}$.  Taking the derivative ends up with the second summation times $x$ (or $b$). I'm not sure how to evaluate the second summation, however.

Comment: Ah, I didn't reload the page and see that others had already explained how to do that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$  a \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n} [{n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k} (2))] = a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2 (b+c)^n  $$
$$  a \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n} [{n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k} (2k)] = a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2 b (b+c)^{n-1} n  $$
$$  a \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n} [{n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k} (3n))] = a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3 (b+c)^n n  $$

The first and third are the [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).  The second comes from "the derivative trick".

We know how to $\sum_k \binom{n}{k}b^k c^{n-k}$, but how do we $\sum_k \binom{n}{k} k b^k c^{n-k}$?  Notice that \begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}b} \binom{n}{k}b^k c^{n-k} &= \binom{n}{k} k b^{k-1} c^{n-k}  \text{, so}  \\
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k b^{k} c^{n-k}
    &= b\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k b^{k-1} c^{n-k}  \\
    &= b \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}b} \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}b^k c^{n-k}  \\
    &= b \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}b}(b+c)^n  \\
    &= b (b+c)^{n-1} n  \text{.}
\end{align*}

We used the binomial formula to discharge the sum.  Note that your original form suggests using $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}c}$ to get the "$3(n-k)$" rather than just distributing as I did.  Also, additional derivatives can be used to deal with higher powers of the index and integration to deal with negative powers of the index.  (I've sometimes wondered if [fractional integration or differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) would make, for instance, $\sum_k \binom{n}{k} \sqrt{k} b^k c^{n-k}$ either easy or a terrible mess.)

Of the three resulting sums, the first is a geometric series in $n$ and the last two are geometric series after applying the derivative trick described previously, so you can evaluate them, add them up, and find that your sum is $\frac{a(3b+c+2)}{(b+c-1)^2}$.

Comment: Except the series of the form $\sum nx^{n-1}$ require a similar differentiation trick.

Comment: I mean after your calculations are done, there is one geometric series and two that require the trick. For example $a\sum_n 3(b+c)^n n$.

Comment: @Milten : Thanks for the suggestion.  Fixed.

Comment: Could you explain the derivative trick in more detail? I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: Also, thanks so much for the answer! I didn't know about the derivative trick and was thus floundering about trying to figure it out.

Comment: @2abysses : Fleshed out the derivative trick a little.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} [{n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k} (2+5k+3(n-k))]=$$

$$=2\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k} +5\sum_{k=0}^{n} k{n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k}+3\sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k){n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k}$$

and

$$2\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k}=2(b+c)^n$$

$$5\sum_{k=0}^{n} k{n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k}=5b\sum_{k=0}^{n} k{n \choose k}b^{k-1}c^{n-k}=5nb(b+c)^{n-1}$$

$$3\sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k){n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k}=3\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose n-k}b^{n-k}c^{k}=3(b+c)^n$$

therefore

$$a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} [{n \choose k}b^{k}c^{n-k} (2+5k+3(n-k))]=5a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (b+c)^n+nb(b+c)^{n-1}$$